# Fetch All replacement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have run into an error in which my fetch all is not working.

Here is the bit of code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$resultSet = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
foreach ($resultSet as $id => $row) {

if ($row['stock'] > 0) {
  $state = "in-stock";
} else {
  $state = "no-stock";
}
```

Here is the error message I am getting.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all().
```

I am not entirely sure how to work around this. Any help and an explanation as to what is going on would be appreciated.

I have looked at a number of similar questions on here, but have not found a working fix.

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` repeatedly to fetch a row at a time until there are none left.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 `mysqli_fetch_all()` is only available if the native drivers are installed, which mostly they aren't.

Comment: @MikeW i did not knew about it. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already looping over the result set by converting it into an array in one single call. You can just loop over the result set itself, wouldn't make a difference in performance

```
//$resultSet = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
if ($row['stock'] > 0) {
  $state = "in-stock";
} else {
  $state = "no-stock";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **mysqli_fetch_array()**
so like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$resultSet = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
foreach ($resultSet as $id => $row) {

if ($row['stock'] > 0) {
  $state = "in-stock";
} else {
  $state = "no-stock";
}
```

Comment: This will only get one row, see manual : `Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both`